# Styling the "sorting turned OFF" modeline message in *Bookmark List* buffer?

Tags: mode-line, bookmarks, mode-line-format

I'm using bookmarks+ and smart modeline and have gone some way to styling the modeline and the *Bookmark List* buffer.  I'd like to change the appearance of the modeline message "sorting turned OFF" in that buffer too.  Currently it looks like:

[image: Bookmark list buffer modeline]

Which does not match the modeline faces. Looking through the list of display faces it seems to be similar to the bmkp-heading face?  Can anyone enlighten me on which faces or settings control the display of this text message?

Thanks,

Stu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) code is in functions `bmkp-bmenu-mode-line-string` (which creates the string, with its faces) and `bmkp-bmenu-mode-line` (which displays that in the mode-line), in file [`bookmark+-bmu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/bookmark%2b-bmu.el).

In the first of these functions you will see that the faces used are (1) `bmkp-heading` (for the `sorting...` information) and (2) one or more of these faces (for the mark counts):

- `bmkp->-mark`
- `bmkp-D-mark`
- `bmkp-t-mark`
- `bmkp-a-mark`
- `bmkp-X-mark`
- `bmkp-*-mark`

That is, the counters that tell you the numbers of each kind of mark (`>`, `D`, `t`, `a`, `X`, and `*`) use the same faces in the mode-line as do those markers in the listing: the counter for marker `>` uses the same face as marker `>`, etc.

You can customize any of the faces, of course.

(Note too that `M-x list-faces-display` can be helpful in identifying faces in places where you cannot easily put point and use `C-u C-x =`.)